# su: Authentication failure (Ignored)

Tags: sudo, pam

Keeping in mind this was working before:

When I try to login as :

```
su jira1
```

I get error:

```
su: Authentication failure
(Ignored)
```

`more /etc/passwd` returns:

```
jira1:x:1003:1003:,,,:/home/jira1:/bin/bash
```

and if I monitor `su jira1`, by tailing `/var/log/auth.log`, I get:

```
Mar 15 10:43:51 jira su[4590]: Successful su for jira1 by root
Mar 15 10:43:51 jira su[4590]: + /dev/pts/1 root:jira1
Mar 15 10:43:51 jira su[4590]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user jira1 by kahmed(uid=0)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the passwd for that user?

Comment: yes and solved, although not sure if that would resolve the application startup error

Comment: Please post the solution to your problem as an answer.

Comment: If @LnxSlck has solved your problem, mark that answer as the accepted one with the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 8):

This will happen when the user's entry is missing from `/etc/shadow` (which is normally updated automatically, unless you have been editing `/etc/passwd` directly).

The `pwconv` utility will fix any inconsistencies. There is a corresponding `grpconv` program for the groups in `/etc/gshadow`.

Comment: `pwconv` isn't the tool for fixing issues. From its man page under section **BUGS**: *Errors in the password or group files (such as invalid or duplicate entries) may cause these programs to loop forever or
       fail in other strange ways. Please run `pwck` and `grpck` to correct any such errors before converting to or from shadow
       passwords or groups.*

Comment: `pwconv` is the right tool to fix missing entries from shadow, assuming that the passwd file is valid. Running `pwck` and `grpck` first is definitely a good idea!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that changing the password for the user solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I got this error during an OS migration after I created a user account and copied the password hash from the old `/etc/shadow`. This error message came everytime I tried to `su migrated_user`—obviously I had **corrupted** this user's entry in the new file.

This **identified** errors:

```
pwck --read-only
```

Once I knew and understood what was wrong, I ran it in normal mode and interactively confirmed to **fix** the errors:

```
pwck
```